# An example for uncountable compact space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Would someone please give an example of a space which is compact but not countably compact space?

Is my example right? : suppose there exist a collection of sets ${\{S_i}\}$ for all $i\in \mathbb Q^*$ ($\mathbb Q^*$ are the set irrational numbers) which covers a set $A$; if $A$ is also covered by limited number of sets from ${\{S_i}\}$ (bijective to ${\{R_j}\}_{j=1}^N$ and $N\ne \infty$ then $A$ is compact but not countably compact space.

Comment: You seem to have the implication backwards: a compact space is countably compact, while a countably compact space needn't be compact. Wikipedia gives an example: the first uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$ with its order topology is countably compact but not compact. Since metrizable spaces are compact if and only if they are countably compact, this is about as simple as any example could ever be.

Comment: @DavidMitra - I know the definitions. I am trying to figure out their differences by example..

Comment: It should be evident that compact implies countably compact. For the converse, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489225/compact-and-countably-compact).

Comment: @Ian - "a compact space is countably compact, while a countably compact space needn't be compact", would you please give examples to show why is so? Wiki's examples are just examples by them I can't figure out the statement you wrote. Thank you

Comment: @DavidMitra - thank you for the link; I don't about $\omega_1$ topology or carnality or order topology. Is there some elementary (undergraduate level) example for why countably compact space may not be compact? Is my example correct? Thank you

Comment: Your example can't be correct as compactness implies countable compactness. For information on $\omega_1$ and on order topologies, see, e.g., Munkres' text. (I know of no  example simpler than $\omega_1$ showing countable compactness does not imply compactness.)

Comment: @AlphaE Sort of "following our nose", order topologies are nice for building non-compact spaces, because if we have a space $X$ with an order topology, a bottom element $0$, and no top element, then $\{ [0,x) : x \in X \}$ is an open cover of $X$. If $X$ is infinite then it has no finite subcover, and in fact if $X$ is uncountable it has no countable subcover. This much works just as well in $\mathbb{R}$ as it does in $\omega_1$. But $\mathbb{R}$ is not countably compact. So we go looking for another order topology on an uncountable set, and pretty much the first thing we find is $\omega_1$.

Comment: [Here's](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEcQFjAGahUKEwjx0dydy-7GAhWMy4AKHVhjBww&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.ou.edu%2F~amiller%2Ftopology2%2FS_Omega.pdf&ei=MHivVfH5MoyXgwTYxp1g&usg=AFQjCNEYKrRnUMzcFuTSmzqCipO35i9C2g&bvm=bv.98197061,d.eXY) a link to a paper outlining the definition and properties of $\omega_1$.

Answer (score 1):

The space $\omega_1$ with the order topology is probably the simplest example. The simplest example that I know that does not require any knowledge of transfinite ordinals is the following one, which requires only a very basic knowledge of countability.

Let $A$ be any uncountable set, and for each $\alpha\in A$ let $D_\alpha=\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology. Let $X=\prod_{\alpha\in A}D_\alpha$ with the product topology. Each point $x\in X$ is a function from $A$ to $\{0,1\}$; for convenience I’ll write $x_\alpha$ instead of $x(\alpha)$, so that $x=\langle x_\alpha:\alpha\in A\rangle$. Note that $X$, being a product of compact Hausdorff spaces, is a compact Hausdorff space.

For each $x\in X$ let $\operatorname{supp}(x)=\{\alpha\in A:x_\alpha=1\}$; I’ll call this set the *support* of $x$. Finally, let $Y=\{x\in X:\operatorname{supp}(x)\text{ is countable}\}$. (Note that *countable* means *finite or countably infinite*.)

Let $p\in X\setminus Y$ be such that $p_\alpha=1$ for each $\alpha\in A$.

- Show that $p\in\operatorname{cl}_XY$ and hence that $Y$ is not closed in $X$. Conclude that $Y$ is not compact. (With no more work you can actually show that $Y$ is dense in $X$.)

It remains to show that $Y$ is countably compact. Since $Y$ is Hausdorff, and hence $T_1$, it suffices to show that $Y$ is [limit point compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point_compact), i.e., that every infinite subset of $Y$ has a limit point in $Y$. Suppose that $S$ is an infinite subset of $Y$. Then we may choose distinct points $y^{(n)}\in S$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. Let

$$A_S=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\operatorname{supp}x^{(n)}\;;$$

$A_S$ is the union of countably many countable sets, so $A_S$ is countable, and $x_\alpha^{(n)}=0$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$ and $\alpha\in A\setminus A_S$.

Let $Z=\prod_{\alpha\in A_S}D_\alpha$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $z^{(n)}\in Z$ be defined by $z_\alpha^{(n)}=y_\alpha^{(n)}$ for each $\alpha\in A_S$. (Thus, $z^{(n)}$ is the projection of $y^{(n)}$ to the subproduct $Z$.) $Z$ is the product of compact spaces, so it’s compact, and the infinite set $\{z^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb N\}$ therefore has a limit point $z\in Z$. Define $y\in Y$ by

$$y_\alpha=\begin{cases}
z_\alpha,&\text{if }\alpha\in A_S\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Note that $y$ definitely is in $Y$, since $\operatorname{supp}(y)\subseteq A_S$, and $A_S$ is countable.

- Verify that $y\in\operatorname{cl}_S\{y^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb N\}\subseteq\operatorname{cl}_YS$ and conclude that $Y$ is countably compact.